# Determining a conditional probability with a random variable.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Assume $X$ is a normal distributed random variable with mean
$2$ and variance $4$. Determine the conditional probability $P(1 \le X \le
3|0 \le X \le 4)$

What I did:
$$Z_0 = \frac{0-2}{2}=-1$$
$$Z_1 = \frac{1-2}{2}=-\frac12$$
$$Z_3 = \frac{3-2}{2}=\frac12$$
$$Z_4 = \frac{4-2}{2}=1$$
using z-score table...
$$P(1 \le X \le 3) = .6915 - .3085 = .383$$
$$P(0 \le X \le 4) = .8413 -.1587 = .6826$$
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$P(1 \le X \le 3|0 \le X \le 4) = .383$$

I know the correct answer is $ 0.560907$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you evaluate the last fraction,  $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ ?

Comment: @leonbloy $\frac{.383*.6826}{.6826}$

Comment: You cannot use the product rule for independent events as $A$ and $B$ are not independent events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it all right, except for the final fraction. The joint event is:

$$A \cap B \equiv (1 \le X \le 3) \cap (0 \le X \le 4)\equiv (1 \le X \le 3)\equiv A$$

(Notice that this holds because here $A \subset B$)

Hence

$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{.383}{.6826}=0.561$$